# Hash anchor tag to a specific navigation tab

Tags: html, tabs, navigation, hashtag

How do you use hash in anchor tags to open a specific navigation tab? For example in my code below, I want to use hash in anchor tags to open my 3rd navigation tab, but it's not jumping there :(

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <section class="tabs"> <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1" checked="checked" />

         <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-1" checked="checked" />
         <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label-1">Radio navigation tab 1</label>

         <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-2" />
         <label for="tab-2" class="tab-label-2">Radio navigation tab 2</label>

         <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector-3" />
         <label for="tab-3" class="tab-label-3">Radio navigation tab 3</label>

         <div class="content">

            <a name="content-3" id="content-1"></a>
            <div class="content-1">
               <h1>Header 1</h1>
               <p>Hello world!</p>
            </div>

            <a name="content-3" id="content-2"></a>
            <div class="content-2">
               <h1>Header 2</h1>
               <p>Hello world!</p>
            </div>

            <a name="content-3" id="content-3"></a>
            <div class="content-3">
               <h1>Header 3</h1>
               <p>Hello world!</p>
            </div>

         </div>

      </section>
   </div>
</body>
```

My url for example: "www.example.com/#content-3" is still opening the first navigation tab so it's still a bit difficult for me to know how to make the hash anchor tag jump to another navigation tab instead of the first tab that is set as the default tab, hope I can get help with this, thanks

Comment: can you post your css and js?

Comment: I don't have my CSS ready yet because I only used it to style my tab looks

Answer (score 0):

First Define the anchor tag like this

```
  <a href="#main-slider">
```

and then redirect it to specific area by

```
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
```